# node execSync errors when |& is present

Tags: node.js, sh

I'm trying to run a simple shell script, in this case we'll say it's `echo foo |& cat > out` (the actual program I want to redirect write output to stderr), and I figured I would like to write this script in js rather than figure out bash control flow for the umpteenth time

```
import { execSync } from 'node:child_process'

execSync('echo foo |& cat > out')
```

since the program works from the command line, it should work in script, right?
'cept instead I get

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `echo foo |& cat > out'
```

the standard pipe operator works just fine from within node, so does anybody know what the deal is with |& here?

Comment: `|&` is a bash extension. `execSync()` uses `sh`.

Comment: The standard syntax is `2>&1 |`

Comment: Why did you tag this `bash` and `zsh`? The error message clearly says `/bin/sh`.

Comment: sorry, it didn't occur to me that node would use a different shell

Comment: `/bin/sh` is the standard POSIX shell. `bash` is the different one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like node was using sh, not bash, and |& is a bash operator only